# Asp.net: create a new server control. Where to start?

Tags: asp.net, servercontrol

I would like to create a Server control that get some parameters and render a form or a gridview. 
My goal is to create a library for standard CRUD operations . 
A server control like this:

```
<asp:myservercontrol database="mydatabase" table="mytable" ... othersparameter typeofcontrol="gridview or listview" >
```

I need an help: where to start ? I've create a new "ServerControl" ?

EDIT: to be more precisely, in my old Winform .NET applications, i used to create a "template" form (with toolbar, buttons, grid), then, with very little code, i "bind" that with database table. 
I would like to recreate this sort of template/server control in ASP.NET.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by reading this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxh7k08z(v=vs.140).aspx

There are a set of server controls that are standard with ASP.NET Web Forms and you can either chose to use one of those as a starting point or start totally from scratch.

You essentially create a C# (or VB.NET) code file and define a class that inherits from a base control type and then override the `RenderContents` method

Here is an example of a custom control:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:WebCustomControl1 runat=server></{0}:WebCustomControl1>")]
    public class WebCustomControl1 : WebControl
    {
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                String s = (String)ViewState["Text"];
                return ((s == null) ? String.Empty : s);
            }

            set
            {
                ViewState["Text"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            output.Write(Text);
        }
    }
}
```